# Python get a set map with list comprehension in one line

Tags: python

Code

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('math', 'a'), ('math', 'a'), ('math', 'b'), ('english', 'c')]
result = defaultdict(set)
for i in data:
    subject, student = i
    result[subject].add(student)
print(result)
# {'math': {'a', 'b'}, 'english': {'c'}}
```

How to get the same result with list comprehension in one line? Thanks.

Comment: Not that it's my place to tell you how to write your code, but fewer lines != better or faster code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is already sorted by subject, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools

data = [("math", "a"), ("math", "a"), ("math", "b"), ("english", "c")]
result = {
    subject: set(student for sj, student in group)
    for subject, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0])
}
print(result)
# {'math': {'b', 'a'}, 'english': {'c'}}
```

Here, `group` stores the tuples, so you need to unpack them into a set.

## Time Comparison

Here's how long it takes each of the solutions here to complete this task 1 million times:

- **For loop**: 0.3681 seconds
- **itertools**: 0.875 seconds
- **no imports**: 1.17 seconds
- **functools**: 0.625 seconds

So in terms of efficiency, just use the for loop.

### timeit code

```
import timeit
default_dict_setup = """
from collections import defaultdict

data = [("math", "a"), ("math", "a"), ("math", "b"), ("english", "c")]
def defaultdict_sol(data):
    result = defaultdict(set)
    for i in data:
        subject, student = i
        result[subject].add(student)
    return result
"""
print(timeit.timeit('defaultdict_sol(data)', setup=default_dict_setup, number=1000000))

itertools_setup = """
import itertools
data = [("math", "a"), ("math", "a"), ("math", "b"), ("english", "c")]
def itertools_sol(data):
    return {
        subject: set(student for sj, student in group)
        for subject, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0])
    }
"""
print(timeit.timeit('itertools_sol(data)', setup=itertools_setup, number=1000000))

noimports_setup = """
data = [("math", "a"), ("math", "a"), ("math", "b"), ("english", "c")]
def noimports_sol(data):
    return {k: {y for x, y in data if x == k} for k in (x for x, _ in data)}
"""

print(timeit.timeit('noimports_sol(data)', setup=noimports_setup, number=1000000))


functools_setup = """
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('math', 'a'), ('math', 'a'), ('math', 'b'), ('english', 'c')]
def functools_sol(data):
    return reduce(lambda d, kv: d[kv[0]].add(kv[1]) or d, data, defaultdict(set))
"""

print(timeit.timeit('functools_sol(data)', setup=functools_setup, number=1000000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it in one line as follows, but it is much less efficient:

```py
data = [('math', 'a'), ('math', 'b'), ('english', 'c')]

output = {k: {y for x, y in data if x == k} for k in (x for x, _ in data)}

print(output) # {'math': {'a', 'b'}, 'english': {'c'}}
```

Comment: result = {key: {value for _key, value in data if _key == key} for key, _ in data}

Comment: Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('math', 'a'), ('math', 'a'), ('math', 'b'), ('english', 'c')]
result = reduce(lambda d, kv: d[kv[0]].add(kv[1]) or d, data, defaultdict(set))
print(result)
# {'math': {'a', 'b'}, 'english': {'c'}}
```